# Difference between “stimmen”, “abstimmen”, and “wählen”

Tags: meaning, difference

I’m confused about the difference in usage between *stimmen, abstimmen,* and *wählen.* Which one means *to vote?* Are you voting for or against something or a person? Is *abstimmen* only for a referendum?

Comment: *Are you voting for or against something or a person?* – Can you please [edit] your question to clarify what you mean by this? Right now, this sentence does not seem to ask a question about the German language. (Note that I do not consider the question closeworthy despite this. It is still a valid question without that sentence.)

Comment: *Are you voting for or against something or a person?* Yes.

Answer (score 11):

Don't worry, native German speakers mix up these terms, too.

Voting for or against a proposal is called *abstimmen*.

> Alle Anwesenden stimmten ab.

*All attendees casted a ballot.*

The verb *stimmen* is used to denote the individual yes/no decision.

> Fast alle stimmten für den Antrag.

*Almost all voted for the proposal.*

> Ich habe dagegen gestimmt.

*I voted against (the proposal).*

When you cast your vote from a selection, it is called *wählen*.

> Wen kann man denn heutzutage überhaupt noch wählen?

*So who you can vote for at all, nowadays?*

BUT people often like to think of a *Wahl* as a yes/no decision, too.

> Diese Wahl war eine Abstimmung für oder gegen Merkel.

*This election was a vote for or against Merkel.*

> Die Menschen haben **für** eine Fortsetzung der jetzigen Koalition **gestimmt**.

*People have **voted for** the continuation of the current coalition.*

Comment: Not only Germans mix it up. Also German native speaker from other countries like Austria, Switzerland, Liechtenstein, Italy (South Tyrol), France (Lothringen), Luxemburg, Belgium and some other countries mix it up. There is another thing that Germans often mix up: They mix up »Germans« and »German native speaker«.

Comment: For the sake of completeness (and because the OP seems to have asked for it with regard to _abstimmen_): all three verbs in question can be used (with different meanings) outside the context of an election or a referendum.

Comment: @Hubert Schölnast: corrected it.

Comment: @Hubert Schölnast: Or they don't presuppose that other German native speakers make the same mistakes Germans do.